# Excluding certain directories from the ignore-glob

Tags: fossil

Is there a way to exclude certain directories from ignore-glob such that (e.g.) .dll files will generally be ignore except if they are in some specific directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you would have to specify all directories you *don't* want to see `.dll` files in, and make sure the directories containing *wanted* DLLs don't match any of the existing ignore-glob entries...

May I ask, what is your use case?

Comment: I was afraid of that. I have a visual studio solution, and I generally don't want to include .dll's in my repository except if they are located in `/lib` in which case they are necessary.